# How to get user list connected using same android application within same intranet(local WiFi)

Tags: android, chat, voip, intranet

I m going develop an android application which is send VoIP Data to other android device which are connected in same Intranet like a college Wi-Fi.My problem is how i can get list of user who are connected with same Wi-Fi ?

Comment: I would probably do something like a WiFi check and then send the data over the network. Might i also suggest [Google](https://www.google.com/) as a better tool to use when asking such questions.

Comment: Can i do broadcasting packet from application ??@CodeMonkey

Comment: Yes, you can use broadcast traffic (if you are prepared for potentially high loss rates) for your clients to find each other, either roll your own or something like bonjour - but a complex wifi setup may not propagate traffic between clients on different access points.  Most real products would solve this problem with a publicly visible server, and use direct traffic only as a possible optimization when/where it seems workable.

Comment: what protocol that i should use for doing this broadcasting @ChrisStratton